# Javascript Facebook API - cannot pull friend's birthdays or other information?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Hey guys so this is what I have and I am simply trying to pull information about my friends but for some reason, the only thing returned is their id and name:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Force based label placement</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.6.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.layout.js?2.6.0"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.geom.js?2.6.0"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : '312321321323',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//blabla.dev/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

  // Here we subscribe to the auth.authResponseChange JavaScript event. This event is fired
  // for any authentication related change, such as login, logout or session refresh. This means that
  // whenever someone who was previously logged out tries to log in again, the correct case below 
  // will be handled. 
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the app know the current
      // login status of the person. In this case, we're handling the situation where they 
      // have logged in to the app.
      testAPI();
      testFriends();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        console.log("not logged in");
      // In this case, the person is logged into Facebook, but not into the app, so we call
      // FB.login() to prompt them to do so. 
      // In real-life usage, you wouldn't want to immediately prompt someone to login 
      // like this, for two reasons:
      // (1) JavaScript created popup windows are blocked by most browsers unless they 
      // result from direct interaction from people using the app (such as a mouse click)
      // (2) it is a bad experience to be continually prompted to login upon page load.
      FB.login();
    } else {
      // In this case, the person is not logged into Facebook, so we call the login() 
      // function to prompt them to do so. Note that at this stage there is no indication
      // of whether they are logged into the app. If they aren't then they'll see the Login
      // dialog right after they log in to Facebook. 
      // The same caveats as above apply to the FB.login() call here.
      FB.login();
    }
  });
  };

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful. 
  // This testAPI() function is only called in those cases. 
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    });
  }

  function testFriends(){
    FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'name,id,location,birthday'}, function(response){
        console.log(response);
        FB.api("/6825119/movies", function(response) { console.log(response)});
    });
  }
  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


</script>
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In login button, provide the `scope` parameter:

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" scope="friends_birthday" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

List of permissions can be found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/).

Also be sure your app is not in `sandbox mode`, otherwise `FB.api` calls don't work in Chrome.